# Subclassing UINavigationBar to have standard visual format

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Our current design spec currently involves a UINavigationBar with standard spacing for the topItem/barItem, and standard font as well for the title.

What's the best practice for doing this? I was considering doing the following:

1. Create a UINavigationBar with the size dimensions for the topItem and barItem objects set with auto-layout constraints, all done programatically.
2. Do not use storyboard for the above, simply define all constraints in code.
3. In the actual view storyboards, have all views with a UINavigationBar use this subclass.

Would this work? Is this the best practice?

Comment: You would have to subclass UINavigationBar and reimplement everything. UINavigationController supports custom class for navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I now working with app and decided the same problem this way:

App has 4 types of UINavigationBar for app. I created BaseNavBar which inherited from UINavigationBar. In .xib I created 4 UINavigationBar and connect it's elements (titleLabel, titleLabel2) to BaseNavBar.h and actions from buttons (from 2 to 4) to BaseNavBar.m. All designs I created in xib.

I created BaseViewContoller which inherited from UIViewController. In viewDidLoad I initialize BaseNavBar of needed type and assign it's elements to self.navigationItem.

In most cases BaseViewContoller decide what type of BaseNavBar it has to use, but in ViewController (which inherited from BaseViewContoller) I can change this type.

After this I create new ViewControllers and don't worry more about UINavigationBar.

If I need to change something in all UINavigationBar - I do it in one place.